# How to make Angular 5 httpClient subscription wait for interceptor response

Tags: httpclient, angular5, interceptor, subscription

Short version:---

How can I make an (http).post().subscription() wait for the intercepted response instead of the 401 response?

---- LONG version ----

In my userHttpService I have this function(Using HttpClient) which is called from a component:

```
 findCostumer(companyName: string){
    let data = {companyName: companyName}
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/angular2/findCostumer.php', JSON.stringify(data),{responseType:'text'})
}
```

To be able to access to findCostumer.php I have to be logged in, since I'm sending a token In header in an Interceptor.

```
const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('jwt')).
                set('refreshToken', localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'))                 
        })
```

Which works fine.

However if the JWT is expired I want to refresh that token with my long-lasting refresh-token.
Here's my whole code for that:

```
intercept(req:HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('jwt') && localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')){
        const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('jwt')).
                set('refreshToken', localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'))                 
        })
       let userhttpservice = this.injector.get(UserHttpService);

        return next.handle(cloned).catch(er=>{
            if(!this.update && er.status == 401)
            {
                 userhttpservice.refreshToken().mergeMap(re=>{
                    console.log(re)
                    this.update = false
                    let json = JSON.parse(re);
                    localStorage.setItem('jwt', json['jwt'])
                    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', json['refreshToken'])
                    let cloned3 = req.clone({
                        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('jwt')).
                        set('refreshToken', localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'))  

                     })
                    return next.handle(cloned3)
                }).subscribe();
                //return next.handle(cloned)
                this.update = true;     

            }
            return Observable.throw('')
        })      
    }
    else
        return next.handle(req) 
}
```

refreshToken-function in userHtppService:

```
 refreshToken(){
    let data =  {'token':localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')};
    return this.Http.post('http://localhost/angular2/refreshToken.php', JSON.stringify(data),{responseType:'text'})  
}
```

Which also works fine. However. on the subscription of findCostumer.php It only get the 401 response. Not the one requested after I refreshed the token. I guess it has to do with that the catch()-operator returns the Observable.throw('') which the subscription takes as the "final" response, ignoring the fact that there will be a new one where I'm granted access after refresh token.
How can I make.subscription() wait for the status 200 page instead?

Comment: I'v tested swicthMap and retry()-operator but no success

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it can be done as follows (but calling `HttpClient` in interceptor is considered as bad practice since it might create cyclic-calls:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {LoginModalComponent} from "@app/shared/components/login-modal/login-modal.component";
import {BsModalService} from "ngx-bootstrap";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HttpAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  private isAuthError(error: any): boolean {
    return error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status == 401;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const intialRequest = request.clone();

    return next.handle(request)
      .catch((error) => {
        if (!this.isAuthError(error)) {
          return Observable.throwError(error);
        }

        this.httpClient.get('/refresh-token').subscribe(res => {
          console.log('Token refreshed');

          // repeating initial request
          return next.handle(intialRequest).do(res => res);
        });
  }
}
```